# orthographic view on object with combined camera on three.js

Tags: three.js

i am trying to use the combined camera (found it under "Examples").
the problem is when i use it in Orthographic mode i still see the arrow and the box helper like in perspective view.
for example, when i am trying to zoom in with the mouse scroll, i can see the plane in the same size (as it supposed to be in orthographic view) but the arrows and the small box between the arrows is getting smaller or bigger.
when i tried to debug it at the renderer function i saw the camera is still in orthograpic mode when it render the arrows.
any idea how can i make all the object to be in orthograpic view but still use the combined camera?

edit:
i am not sure which part of the code i should post so i add a picture to describe my problem.
you can see that i am in an orthographic camera and i'm trying to zoom in and i can see the axis arrow getting bigger or smaller.

[the difference between the plane when zooming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCbTa.png)

Comment: fiddle would be helpful

Comment: Put the code on SO, not in a fiddle

Comment: @gman both a fiddle and the code on SO is the best for everyone :D

Comment: Why do you need the fiddle? Code runs just fine on SO

Comment: i am not sure what do you mean with fiddle and SO, i am pretty new to three.js :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a possible answer which worked for me:
under TransformControls.js
change the update function to:

```
 scale = (camera.inOrthographicMode == true)? 100 : worldPosition.distanceTo(camPosition ) / 6 * scope.size;
```